# Programmable Melody chips

Tags: midi, music

Is there a component, (that is not Raspberry Pi or other mini computer it would be too costly for my purpose), comparable to simple melody chips like UM66 or BT66 But programmable in nature, so that I can use to play a MIDI music file on loop? **Preferably suggest me a circuit diagram to do this with simple radio supply**.

It would be a very simple circuit:
[image]

It would work like those music playing postcards, so there will be a switch, but nothing more complicated around it.

I have only base knowledge in electronics so my search for this wasn't successful. I need a component or circuit that does this. I could build it if needed, but I would prefer a ready to use component if exists.

Comment: Even those playing postcards are basically a specialized µC

Comment: "it would be an overkill", no it would not. For midi you need to have an RS232 interface and a waveform generator. There is nothing smaller, cheaper or easier then e.g. a 6-pin processor.

Comment: you can consider using the DSP-G1 Voice Chip [AdaFruit link](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2400). It's basically a pre-programmed uC.

Comment: you have to be careful: "MIDI file" means ... File. A file is a computer-with-an-operating-system-that-knows-what-a-filesystem-is concept, and thus, to deal with files, you need a computer that fits this description. MIDI is "just" the things *contained* in that file, and you wouldn't need a "computer-with-an-operating-system-that-knows-what-a-filesystem-is" just to synthesize sounds. But then you'd ask yourself where this MIDI comes from, and you'll probably end up with "preferably, from a file stored somewhere", and then, no, nothing says your raspberry pi is overkill.

Comment: (and no, it won't be a very simple circuit. What makes you think it is?)

Comment: @Oldfart still not a full computer with OS. But you help a lot with keywords in your comment. Also all the keywords in the comments helps a lot! Thank you

Comment: @MarcusMüller This is why I am asking. I know I do not know this field well. And I already know much more now, than before the comments. So really thank you.

Comment: Do you understand that a MIDI file doesn't actually contain any sounds - just "note on, note off" info? so what you are actually asking for is a single chip synthesiser?

Comment: Proposing converting MIDI file to MP3, save the only file onto SD-card, and make some $5 appliance play it in the loop. This way you will 100% know how it will sound; with MIDI file actual sound will depend on the samples coded in the MIDI player.

Comment: @dmb I udnerstand midi file, but I did not understand how it plays on simple electronics. But now I know. Lot of these comments could be answers that I accept.

Comment: Some 3 Pin IC Chip like UM66 or BT66 does the exact same thing but i m not sure is there a way to reprogram them, nor im sure the exact file format they uses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments gave me several keywords and resources to find the component I imagined. The [Adafruit Audio FX Mini Sound Board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2341) does exactly what I want in my project. I can put a sound file (not midi, but its fine) on it. I can trigger it to loop the song. Thank you for the helpful comments.